# Buying a second hand Fujinon lens in Osaka

Tags: japan, shopping, photography, kyoto, osaka

I am Going back for the third time in Japan next summer.  I am looking for shops recommendation to buy another lens for my Fujifilm digital camera.

Are there shops to buy reliable second hand lenses in Osaka?

My trip starts in Osaka, after that we go to Kyoto. So shops in Kyoto are also a good answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being a Nikonist myself, I can't recommend any shops for Fuji in particular, but for camera gear of any kind the place to go is **Nipponbashi** (日本橋) aka **Den-Den Town** ("Electric Town"), Osaka's equivalent to Tokyo's Akihabara, near Namba station.  [Tokiwa](http://www.tokiwa-camera.co.jp/03shop/index.html) (トキワ) is the big name here, but there's a bunch of others as well.

[Naniwa](http://www.cameranonaniwa.co.jp/shop/shinsaibashi_map/index.html) (ナニワ) near **Shinsaibashi** is also worth checking out, it's a large chain but their used-gear speciality shop (中古買取センター) is located here.  There's another cluster near **Umeda** station with the [Kitamura](http://blog.kitamura.jp/27/4359/index.html) (キタムラ) chain's equivalent, used camera dealers [Obayashi](http://www.camera-no-ohbayashi.co.jp/shopinfo.html#pageImg) (大林), and some more Naniwa shops as well as well.

[This map shows](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?oe=UTF8&ie=UTF8&msa=0&mid=zPagdqqsS6k8.kgKcGtPczv_s) quite a few of these, but note that some shops shown (eg. Yodobashi and BIC) only sell new gear, and I think the one Naniwa outlet listed is gone.  These don't see very many tourists, so expect English ability to be limited.